# Merge selected nodes of the two XML files

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument

Let's say I have two XML files which has the same structure. I need to create new XML file with same structure which contain the selected nodes from initial two XML files.

I will try to explain again with bellow example.

`input1.xml` :

```
<parent>
    <item id="100">
         ...
    </item>
    <item id="101">
         ...
    </item>
    <item id="102">
         ...
    </item>
    <item id="103">
         ...
    </item>
</parent>
```

`input2.xml` :

```
<parent>
    <item id="200">
         ...
    </item>
    <item id="201">
         ...
    </item>
    <item id="202">
         ...
    </item>
    <item id="203">
         ...
    </item>
</parent>
```

Now I need select the nodes which have id `100,103` from `input1.xml` and `202,203` from `input2.xml`. Also it should be in the order of `203,100,103,202` and final result would be look like bellow.

`result.xml` :

```
<parent>
    <item id="203">
         ...
    </item>
    <item id="100">
         ...
    </item>
    <item id="103">
         ...
    </item>
    <item id="202">
         ...
    </item>
</parent>
```

It is not necessary to create new file, if I can edit the `input2.xml` in the way it looks like `result.xml`, that would be the ideal solution.

**What I have done so far :**

My approach is first delete the nodes from the `input2.xml` and then add the nodes to that from `input1.xml`. 
I have following function to delete nodes from `input2.xml` file.

eg: call `delete_record(200,'input2.xml','result.xml')` can delete the node 200 and I can repeat it in the similar manner.

```
function delete_record($id, $input, $output){
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    $xml->load($input);

    $deals = $xml->getElementsByTagName('item');
    foreach ($deals as $deal) {
        $deal_id = $deal->getElementsByTagName('id')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        if ($deal_id == $id) {
            $id_matched = true;
            $deal->parentNode->removeChild($deal);
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($id_matched == true) {
        if ($xml->save($output)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But still I am struggling to find a way how to add nodes to the same `result.xml` file and how to make the order.

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to mess with deletion, just do what you need to. Pick nodes by id from both files, and put it in order:

```
// merge all nodes by Id
function getNodesById($id, ...$xpaths) {
  $result = [];
  foreach($xpaths as $xpath) {
    foreach($xpath->query("//item[@id='$id']") as $node) {
      $result[] = $node;
    }
  }
  return $result;
}


// load source documents
$xml1 = new DOMDocument();
$xml1->load(....);
$xpath1 = new DomXpath($xml1);

$xml2 = new DOMDocument();
$xml2->load(....);
$xpath2 = new DomXpath($xml2);

// create result document
$result = new DOMDocument();
$parent = $result->createElement("parent");
$result->appendChild($parent);

// populate result document with nodes:
foreach([203, 100, 103, 202] as $id) {
  $nodesToInsert = getNodesById($id, xpath1, xpath2);
  if (count($nodesToInsert) !== 1) {
    // resolve conflicts, if any
    throw new Exception("Id $id is not found or not unique.");
  }
  $parent->appendChild($result->importNode($nodesToInsert[0], true));
}

// or save it to a file
echo $result->saveXml();
```